# Adding leaflet layerGroup options dynamically

Tags: leaflet, polylineoptions

I'm using the leaflet snaking polyline to draw a route on a map with multiple markers, and have it working. However, I want to make the snaking speed a setting that the user can change, so I need to be able to modify the default snaking speed when I add the layerGroup to the layer. To add the layer with the default snaking speed  I simply have the following line of code (and it works):

```
        layerGrp.addLayer( endMarker );
        layerGrp.addTo(polyLayer).snakeIn();
```

But I want to really add

```
    layerGrp.addLayer(endMarker, { snakingSpeed: snakingSpeedFromUser } );
    layerGrp.addTo(polyLayer).snakeIn();
```

I've tried what's shown above, and also just

```
    layerGrp.addLayer( {snakingSpeed: snakingSpeedFromUser } );
```

But both of them give me a runtime error of

```
         Uncaught (in promise) Error: The provided object is not a Layer.
```

Polylayer is a layergroup so I can show/hide the polylines. Here's where it is added to the map:

```
 var gridLayer = L.layerGroup([]); 
 var polyLayer = L.layerGroup([]); 
 var overlayMaps = { "Track": polyLayer, "Grid": gridLayer }; 
 var layerControls = { "Map": mapLayer, 
                       "Track": polyLayer, 
                       "Grid": gridLayer };
```

How can I add the options to the layerGroup dynamically at runtime?

Thanks......

Comment: What is your `polyLayer`?

Comment: You cannot format comments, that is why you should edit your question instead.

Comment: Does anyone out there have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is a little bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. You should probably edit your question, explaining what you mean by modifying the speed when you adf the layer group, etc.